# How to make my magazine online?

Tags: website-design, adobe-indesign, pdf, compression

I have created magazine in iD for print. Therefore its size is very big. 
How can I comprime its size so I can use it online?

Maybe some settings of iD would help or software?
How do you publish pdf on your webpage?

Thanks

Comment: Try and export it as a *.pdf using the 'smallest file size' preset as a starting point.

Comment: If you want to use a plataform, I higly recommend [Issuu](http://issuu.com/).

Comment: I prefer to not use platform / pay monthly / have ads next to my magazine. its sturtup = no much money.

Comment: yes, smaller size whould help, but what are the best settings to have good quailty and small file size?

Comment: Even the question was answered, anyone can write its maybe better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 2 diferent questions here.

1) You need to configure your export settings of the pdf. The pdf for printing probably has the images in 300 dpi, cmyk, and with zip compression or no compression at all. So you need to configure the export settings to rgb, jpg compression, and lets say 100 dpi on the images. The fonts must be embeded in the file, and protect the file against editing.

The jpg compression its about trial and error, so you have a file you like in quality and size. You can play a little with the dpi of the images as well.

2) How do you publish it online? Well, that depends on your knoledge of web technologies, html, css.

The simplest option is to put a link to download the file, but you can use some kind of flip page software. https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=flip+page

The traditional one was based on flash, but there are some based in html5. Check the features you like, comparing diferent options including licence.

One more advanced feature is to clasify your magazine, by date and contents, but that probably will lead you to prepare some kind of database search option.

If you dont have a webpage you probably can install wordpress and use one flip page wordpress plug in. https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=wordpress+flip+page+plugin